# Using results of case_when from first line and using the results to evaluate second condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am fairly new to R and trying to clean data. I am using case_when to assign Yes, No and Unknown to a variable. I want to assign the same variable No and Unknown if it gets assigned Yes in the first statement and have other statements true or false.

This is what I have:

```
    ID col1  col2  
    1   Ball  a  
    2   NA    c   
    3   Bat   b
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
    ID col1  col2  x
    1   Ball  a   No
    2   NA    c   Yes
    3   Bat   b   Unknown
```

```
 mutate(x = case_when(
      is.na(col1) == TRUE ~ "Yes",
      !is.na(col1) == TRUE & (col2 %in% c("a", "b")|
      (col2 == "YES" & x == "Unknown" ) == TRUE ) ~ "No"),
TRUE ~ "Unknown"
))
```

Basically I want to use the results of x from first case_when and use it in 2nd line of code. I basically want my column x to be "Yes", if col1 is NA. And if col1 is not missing and (col2 %in% c("a", "b") or col1 == "Bat" and x = "Yes") then set x = "No"

Is there a way to get this to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't follow what you're trying to do. It would help if you could describe a specific example with a line or two of data and what output you expect.

Comment: Also, it's redundant to test if a test is TRUE. You can write `is.na(col1)` instead of `is.na(col1) == TRUE` because the first part is already equal to TRUE.

Comment: @JonSpring This is what my table looks like, see updates in question above. I basically want my column x to be Yes, if col1 is NA. 
And if col1 is not missing and (col2 %in% c("a", "b") or col1 == "Bat" and x = "Yes") then set x = "No" .
My problem is how to use the condition of x = "Yes" from part 1 in the second part of case_when condition, i am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

`case_when` lets you list a series of tests, and assign the value associated with the first tests that passes (ie is TRUE).

In most cases, you can get what you want if you think carefully through the sequencing of your tests. In this question, your instructions, your comments, and your output table don't seem to be consistent with each other, which makes it hard to answer. Here, I have taken the last text you edited and used that as a basis for the logic:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(
    # First, test if col1 is NA -- if so, x will be "Yes" and we are done with the case_when.
    is.na(col1)  ~ "Yes",

    # For the second test, I'll rely on the text of your latest edit:
    #   "And if col1 is not missing and (col2 %in% c("a", "b") or 
    #    col1 == "Bat" and x = "Yes") then set x = "No"
    # (Note, this doesn't seem to be consistent with your output table...)

    # To get here means the prior test was false: col1 must have a non-NA value.
    col2 %in% c("a", "b") | col1 == "Bat"  ~ "No",

    # Otherwise, set to unknown
    TRUE  ~ "Unknown"
  ))

  ID col1 col2   x
1  1 Ball    a  No
2  2 <NA>    c Yes
3  3  Bat    b  No
```